# How can I verify whether a component is compatible with Windows 8.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, bing-maps, compiler-warnings, visual-c++-runtime

My VS2103/Windows Store gives me two warnings, about "Bing Maps for C#" (in my case):

*Project "Platypus" depends upon SDK "Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic v1.0" which supports apps targeting "Windows 8.0". To verify whether "Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic v1.0" is compatible with "Windows 8.1", contact the SDK author or see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309181.*

...and C++ Runtime Package (not sure why I need that in my C# project):

*"Project "Platypus" depends upon SDK "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package v11.0" which was released originally for apps targeting "Windows 8.0". To verify whether "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package v11.0" is compatible with "Windows 8.1", contact the SDK author or see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309181*

Going to the link provided gives information about a couple of other packages, but not those above. How do I verify whether my "Bing Maps for C#" and "C++ Runtime Package" are compatible with Windows 8.1?

When I go to Manage NuGet Packages, and select Updates > All, I get, "No items found"

When I go to Manage NuGet Packages's Online tree node, and search for "bing maps sdk" I get scads of Bing Maps-related packages, but I don't see the "official" or "base" package (Microsoft's Bing Maps SDK).

Comment: What part of "contact the SDK author" in both of the messages is unclear?

Comment: The SDK author is Microsoft, right? And they add the link for "where to go from here" but it gives me no useful info; being that they are MS packages, they should be able to resolve the problem in-place, or at least give clear direction on what needs to be done. Jumping through hoops is for circus performers.

Comment: Yes, the SDK author would be MS, who would be the ones to contact. This is StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps SDK is not a nugget package. It is a Visual Studio extension. If you want to use Bing Maps in Windows 8.1 there was a new SDK built which has a lot of bug fixes and added features when compared to the Win8 SDK. Steps to migrate your app are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456475.aspx#upgrade